# ASP.Net Razor C# Variables Accessible to All Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, razor-2, razor-pages

For starters, please forgive me and please correct me on my terminology. I am quite sure of the correct words to use for what I am trying to accomplish.

I have been given the task of building an ASP.Net Razor web site. It is something new to me. I am very proficient in PHP and ASP Classic. What I need to be able to figure out is how to declare a variable that is accessible everywhere. I do not know if in the .net world you call it a global variable or application variable or something else. But, here is how I would do this in Classic ASP.

In Classic ASP, I would have a file named VarFunct.asp. It would be the file that I declare my variables and have various functions I would access from anywhere. I would include the VarFunct.asp file on all of my pages. Anyway this is what I am really trying to do (written in how I would do it in Classic ASP)…

```
SelLoc = Request("SelLoc")
If Len(Trim(SelLoc)) = 0 Then
    SelLoc = "All"
End If
```

In this case, Request("SelLoc") could be Request.QueryString or Request.Form. Then anywhere in my website I could use the variable SelLoc. So, in short... I need to be able to set a variable. Check to see if it is set by Request.Form, if not, check Request.QueryString, if not set the value to “All”.  How do I write this? And where do I put it?

When I created the website using Visual Studio 2012, I selected ASP.NET Web Site (Razor V2).

This seems like it should be such a basic fundamental task of any website that has any kind of server side programming, but trying to find information and documentation online is near impossible, but probably because I am not using the correct terms for my question. I have not found any Razor tutorials that talk about setting variables that can be used globally across the website.

If someone could please help me out here by either telling me what I need to do or point me to a good tutorial, that would be great.

Comment: Do you want these variables to be unique per user, or application-wide for all users?

Answer (score 2):

what you are looking for is called [Static Class/Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

This will allow you to store and share data for the whole application.

BUT! since web server is multi-threaded, you wouldn't want to do this or else you might run into the case where the data is overwritten by another request before you finished the current one.

If you need to pass data from controller to your View you can use `ViewBag` dynamic object

If you need to use the data anywhere else (for example in a helper class) then do

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["VariableName"] = something
```

It is basically a dictionary and each request will have a different `Application` object

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this.

For your example I would assume that this particular variable can be different for different users that are using the application at the same time.  This is more of a Session scope than Application scope.

In this case you could simply use inheritance and make a base controller and/or base view model class that all your other controllers and/or view models inherit from.  This way you can pass it back and forth between the view and controller and read/update it whenever you need to.

You could also use the Request and HttpContext and Session objects that are built into asp.net, if they fit your need.  A brief overview of some of their functionality can be found here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/api-reference/asp-net-web-pages-api-reference --- google searching specific ones yields tons of results.

If you truly want Application scope, you can of course use a static class for you utilize static methods.  Then you don't need to include the class in every other class, but you would need to fully name qualify the method when you call it.

I would not recommend static variables at this level though.  I can't imagine very many things that would need to change for every single user that you would change while the application instance is running.  Most of these sorts of items that we use are caches (generally db lookups and such, that we don't want to retrieve from the db each time, and RARELY get updated).  If you utilize caches, be very aware of your thread safety when updating them.  Here is an msdn on caching:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx --- Or application configuration settings, like the application environment.  We pull most of those from a config file, and they are read only, we don't change them within a running instance of the application.